# What is lua_pcall doing here?

Tags: c, lua

I am trying to learn lua and I seem to be stuck here.

For some reason the following code doesn't actually run the lua file.

```
int main()
{
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    if(!luaL_loadfile(L, "./src/luaconf.lua") || !lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)) 
    {
            lua_getglobal(L, "width");
            lua_getglobal(L, "height");

            if(!lua_isnumber(L, -2)) 
            {
                    luaL_error(L, "width isn't a number");
            }
            else
            {
                    width = lua_tointeger(L, -2);
            }

            if(!lua_isnumber(L, -1)) 
            {
                    luaL_error(L, "height isn't a number");
            }
            else
            {
                    height = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
            }
    }

    printf("%i x %i", width, height);

    return 0;

 }
```

I know that if I change `if(!luaL_loadfile(L, "./src/luaconf.lua") || !lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)` to `if(luaL_dofile(L, "./src/luaconf.lua"))` it would work but I want to know why the above code doesn't work.

Shouldn't lua_pcall run the lua code? If not why not?

luaconf.lua

```
width = 500
height = 40
```

Comment: I just noticed you have different "if statement" in the document and in the code, my answer is based on the code. If that's not true, please comment on my answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Minor mistake. The code is the right one and thanks for the answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in the code:

```
if(!luaL_loadfile(L, "./src/luaconf.lua") || !lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
```

if `luaL_loadfile` succeeds, it returns `LUA_OK` which has the value of `0`, so the left operand of `||` evaluates as `1`, according to short circuit, `lua_pcall` won't be executed.

So what you want is probably:

```
if ((luaL_loadfile(L, "./src/luaconf.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
{
    //error handle
}
else
{
    //normal handle
}
```

Comment: if that is that case then wouldn't using `&&` instead of `||` be preferable?

Comment: @thecodethinker If you choose to negate each expression with `!`, then yes, you should use `&&` instead.